# Checking if a hidden field exists in freeform

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

My client publishes event sign up forms using Freeform 1, under Craft 2.9.

They would these forms to automatically shut down when a certain submission count is reached. The submission count will differ depending on the event/form.

I had planned to let authors add a hidden field to the Freeform composer which specified a maximum number of submissions. Then on the template, check that the hidden field has a value, and use the submission limiting logic.

The problem is I don't know how to check if a hidden field exists hidden fields don't seem to be accessible through the form>pages>rows>fields objects, and render automatically as part fo the form.renderTag function.

Is there a way to check a hidden field exists when rendering a form?